# Condition that previous week days are up days

Tags: pine-script

The following script creates this https://www.tradingview.com/x/PeSh31NK/

```
//@version=4
study("Session bars", overlay= true)
t = time(timeframe.period, "1700-1700:2")
bgcolor(not na(t) and close / open > 1 ? color.aqua : na, transp = 80)
```

If I would like to put in the condition that Friday and Thursday has to be an up day as well, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:2` represents Monday.
So `:256` represents Monday, Thursday and Friday.
You can read about how that works in [Session and time information](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Sessions_and_time_functions.html#)

This code will include Thursday and Friday as well.

```
//@version=4
study("Session bars", overlay= true)
t = time(timeframe.period, "1700-1700:256")
bgcolor(not na(t) and close / open > 1 ? color.aqua : na, transp = 80)
```

Comment: Thanks, this gives them the color, but the criteria for giving color should be that all three days are positive days. https://www.tradingview.com/x/k0uPlGua/

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean that Thu, Fri and Mon must be up days, and then you want those 3 days colored? And if one of those days is a down day, none are colored?

Comment: Yes, that was what I hoped to achieve!

Comment: I don't think this can be done. That would require to apply a `bgcolor()` to a bar in the past. Suppose Thursday and Friday are up days, but Monday is a down day, then you'd have to undo the `bgcolor()` on Thursday and Friday. I don't know of a way to do that.

Comment: Aha, I see! That is helpful, as I am trying to learn Pine Script I am stumbling a bit here and there, and it is a bit annoying when I don't understand why (it is not everything that is thoroughly explained in the user manual when one is not well known in programming on a general basis) .. But I take it from your'e answer it is because bgcolor() is inserted by one bar at the time rule, hence it is the wrong tool for such a use.